# How to apply code styles to Angular template code in WebStorm?

Tags: angular, webstorm

Is there a way to define the order of Angular properties when using code reordering?

I'm looking for an option to define the order of HTML attributes used in Angular, such as `*ngIf`, `[binding]`, `(event)`, etc.

[image]

*Inset image: I'm trying in different ways.*

---

This is the template property alignment style I want.

```
<!-- bad -->
<my-app-component
  (click)="onClick($event)"
  [(ngModel)]="fooBar"
  class="foo"
  #myComponent
  [bar]="theBar"
  @fade
  foo="bar"
  *ngIf="shouldShow"
  (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"
></my-app-component>

<!-- good -->
<my-app-component
  *ngIf="shouldShow"
  @fade
  #myComponent
  class="foo"
  foo="bar"
  [bar]="theBar"
  [(ngModel)]="fooBar"
  (click)="onClick($event)"
  (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"
></my-app-component>
```

Comment: For me, without any additional settings, WebStorm arranges the attributes in the following order: Variable declarations (#), events, structural directives (*), animations (@), two-way bindings, property bindings, attributes. Is this the same for you? I'm afraid you cannot configure the order though.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Hi Derulo, Thanks for the comment. I see.. So, is customization impossible?